# Macro to write formula with variables in multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a Gantt chart that updates the graphics with conditional Formating, but in order to do it I need to write a formula that changes in each cell, I already wrote a macro to do it and it works, but after they are written every cell needs to be double-clicked in order for it to work, after you double click it it updates on its own, so automatic calculation is enabled, I can make them work if I use Text to Columns, but they are about 650 columns and the macro to do it automatically is not working.

Suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

this is the code I'm using:

```
Sub formula_writer()
Row = 2
col = 9
i = 0
row2 = ActiveCell.Row
x = 0
    While i <= 100
        If i >= 99 Then
            x = x + 1
            ActiveSheet.Range("i9").Offset(x, 0).Select
            i = 0
            col = 9
            row2 = row2 + 1
        End If
        If x = 20 Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            aCell = Cells(Row, col).Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True)
            Selection.Formula = "" & "=SI" & "($A$" & row2 & " <> " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " , " & aCell & " , " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
            ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            i = i + 1
            col = col + 1
        End If
    Wend
i = 0
x = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the code for formula SI? Is that a UDF?

Comment: Sorry, my Office is in spanish so "SI" would be "IF"
the formula i'm trying to write is =IF($A19<>"",$I$2,"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code quite a bit, but the main issue is that the formula in the code (whether R1C1 or A1) should use the English version of the formula name. Try this update:

```
Sub formula_writer()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("I10:DD28").numberformat="General"
Range("I10:DD28").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[10]C1<>"""",R2C,"""")"

Application.Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! that's much simpler, but i get the same issue with the formula not updating, it gives me a #NAME? error until i double click it

Comment: I've added a numberformat change to the code, your range might be formatted as text initially?

Comment: i tried your new suggestion but it has the same issue, my cells were actually formatted as Date, but even if i change the format it gives me the #NAME? error

Comment: let's try using the English version. Change the SI in the code to IF.